# Quantum mechanic particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, supersymmetry, hamiltonian

In non relativistic quantum mechanic, we are dealing with a problem involving a particle in one dimensional space, and it has been given the potential and it reads:

$$V(x)~=~A'(x)^2-\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}}A''(x).\tag{1}$$

The kinetic terms is the usual $p^2/2m$. How can I show that the Hamiltonian of the system is semi-definite positive?

Comment: What are $A'(x)$ and $A''(x)$? Are they derivatives of a function $A(x)$ or just two separate functions?

Comment: re: question tags - is susy or operators really relevant here?

Comment: @Qmechanic Are you sure you meant to add the "supersymmetry" (or for that matter, "operators") tag here?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: Related question on Math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1337079/11127

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Think of way to write the Hamiltonian as

$$\hat{H}~=~ -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2} +V(x)~=~\hat{B}^{\dagger}\hat{B} ~\geq~0 $$

for some first-order differential operator

$$\hat{B}~=~a(x)\frac{d}{dx} +b(x) ,$$

with suitable functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$. 
Here the potential $V(x)$ is given by formula (1). Can you see what the operator $\hat{B}$ should/must be?

By the way, the function $A(x)$ is known as a superpotential, cf. e.g. Ref. 1, which also explains the connection to SUSY QM.

References:

1. F. Cooper, A. Khare, and U. Sukhatme, *Supersymmetry and Quantum Mechanics,*     [Phys. Rept. 251 (1995) 267](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(94)00080-M), [arXiv:hep-th/9405029](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9405029); Chapter 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Why the function $A(x)$ is known as a superpotential? And also, i don't understand how supersymmetry enter in this problem. However i just try to write the Hamiltonan as you suggest but i couldn't because there are 2 additional terms.

Comment: Ok, i'm reading the article.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, i have another question, maybe caused by my ignorance. Why the dagger of $\hat{B}$ take a minus in front of the derivative terms ?

Comment: This is basically the same reason that the momentum operator $\hat{p}=\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ is a Hermitian operator.

Comment: Correction to the answer (v3): The superpotential is actually $A^{\prime}(x)$ not $A(x)$.